# Stopping multiple threads at once

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

What do I miss in the program below with threads waiting for a `condition_variable_any` to determine when to stop ? In the *program listed below*, the threads stop in an impredictable way; some **before** the call to `notify_all` and some don't stop at all.

The condition variable used is defined as below:

```
static std::mutex interrupt_mutex;
static std::condition_variable_any interrupt_cv;
```

The threads **check if it is time to stop** as below:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
const auto cv_status = interrupt_cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
const auto timeout_expired = cv_status == std::cv_status::timeout;
if (!timeout_expired)
{
    quit = true;
}
```

The main thread **signals the threads to stop** as below:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
interrupt_cv.notify_all();
```

A possible output looks like:

```
Thread  1> Received interrupt signal at iteration 2
Thread  1> Terminate
Thread  2> Received interrupt signal at iteration 2
Thread  2> Terminate
Thread  4> Received interrupt signal at iteration 2
Thread  4> Terminate
**** Requesting all threads to stop ****
Waiting for all threads to complete...
```

Below the **complete code** that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

static std::mutex interrupt_mutex;
static std::condition_variable_any interrupt_cv;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_handles;
    for (int thread_idx = 0; thread_idx < 4; ++thread_idx)
    {
        thread_handles.emplace_back(std::thread([thread_idx](const int thread_id)
        {
            int num_iterations = 0;
            auto quit = false;
            while (!quit)
            {
                // Fake processing time during the lock for testing purpose
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
                ++num_iterations;

                // Check if need to stop with a timeout of 200ms 
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
                    const auto cv_status = interrupt_cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    if (const auto timeout_expired = cv_status == std::cv_status::timeout; !timeout_expired)
                    {
                        printf("Thread %2d> Received interrupt signal at iteration %d\n", thread_id, num_iterations);
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            printf("Thread %2d> Terminate\n", thread_id);
        }, thread_idx + 1));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    // Signals all threads to stop
    {
        printf("**** Requesting all threads to stop ****\n");
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
        interrupt_cv.notify_all();
    }

    // Wait until all threads stop
    printf("Waiting for all threads to complete...\n");
    std::ranges::for_each(thread_handles, [](std::thread& thread_handle)
    {
        thread_handle.join();
    });

    printf("Program ends\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Condition variable doesn't look like the right tool for this job. The condition variable will stop and wait on each iteration, slowing things down. If this isn't the behaviour you want, I think a `std::atomic<bool>` or [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) would be a better choice.

Comment: OK I understand I should use an std::atomic_flag. But this said, why the threads are not stopped reliably? The reason I use a timeout so the threads must do something else and then check periodically if they must stop.

Comment: Further, don't use cv's for state. That isn't what they're intended for. That's what predicate data is for. If there is a reason to "know" when a cv wait operation has timed out (perhaps to shrink a thread pool down to some minimum size, etc.) that's ok, but the core wait should still be based on external predicate data protected by the mutex.

Comment: I ran your sample code, and the threads all stopped... eventually.   All but one or two stopped right away. But in my last run (6 threads) the last to terminate was thread 3 at iteration 232.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `condition_variable` is meant to signal threads *when a condition changes* (ie, such as when a *shared variable* changes value).  But your code has no *condition*.  You are trying to use the `condition_variable` itself as a quit signal, and that is not what it is meant for.  `notify_all()` will only wake up threads that are actively waiting on the `condition_variable` at that exact moment. Threads that are not waiting on it, because they are busy doing something else, will not receive that signal to terminate.  But those threads will need to detect the *condition* once they are ready to wait.  So the *condition* needs to be something more persistent. That is why your code is not working correctly.

In this case, you can simply move your `quit` variable to global scope, next to the `condition_variable` and `mutex`. Setting that `quit` variable will act as your *condition* that you can signal waiting threads about.  You can then use the overloaded version of `wait_for()` that will let you check the current state of `quit` (to ignore spurious awakenings).

Try something more like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

static std::mutex interrupt_mutex;
static std::condition_variable_any interrupt_cv;
static bool quit = false;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_handles;
    for (int thread_idx = 0; thread_idx < 4; ++thread_idx)
    {
        thread_handles.emplace_back(std::thread([thread_idx](const int thread_id)
        {
            int num_iterations = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                // Fake processing time outside the lock for testing purpose
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
                ++num_iterations;

                // Check if need to stop with a timeout of 1s 
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
                    const bool signaled = interrupt_cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1), [](){ return quit; });
                    if (signaled) break;
                }
            }

            printf("Thread %2d> Received interrupt signal at iteration %d\n", thread_id, num_iterations);
            printf("Thread %2d> Terminate\n", thread_id);
        }, thread_idx + 1));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    // Signals all threads to stop
    printf("**** Requesting all threads to stop ****\n");
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
        quit = true;
    }
    interrupt_cv.notify_all();

    // Wait until all threads stop
    printf("Waiting for all threads to complete...\n");
    std::ranges::for_each(thread_handles, [](std::thread& thread_handle)
    {
        thread_handle.join();
    });

    printf("Program ends\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explaination. I know better now on how to use a condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code and both have the same solution.

1. Spurious wake-up. If your `wait_for` is ended because of SW, you will have your condition satisfied, although no one actually requested it to wake-up/end.
2. What if your thread isn't holding a lock and not sleeping and your main thread notifies all? Note, that notifications aren't stored anywhere so if you missed one, you won't get one later. So those threads that missed will never terminate.

To fix both issues you need another flag, which will tell your threads that job is done and they have to stop.

```
static bool stop = false;
//...
if (stop) // Instead of if (const auto timeout_expired = cv_status == std::cv_status::timeout; !timeout_expired)
//...
printf("**** Requesting all threads to stop ****\n");
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(interrupt_mutex);
stop = true;
interrupt_cv.notify_all();
```